# Redux doesn't set the initialState. Action dispatch fails too

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I did set the initialState into the reducer as below, but **the Detail button didn't disabled when I load the page and didn't turn enable when I click the Disable button**. The console.log("1") in reducer is showing correctly when I call the action.

```
var initialState2 = {
        disabled:true
        }
```

**action creators**

```
function clickDisable() {
  return {
      type: 'CLICK_DISABLE'
  }
}
```

**reducer here**

```
function reducreForButtonGroup2(state = initialState2, action) {
  if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
    return 0
  }
  var disabled;
  switch(action.type) {
      case 'CLICK_DISABLE': {
          console.log("1");
          if(state.disabled==true){
              return {
                  disabled: false
                  }
          }else{
              return {
                  disabled: true
                  }
          }
      }
      default :{
          return state
      }
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
 var DetailButton = React.createClass({ 
                clickDisable(event) {  
                    this.props.dispatch(clickDisable());  
                }  ,
                
              render() {
                    
                const { disabled } = this.props;   
                    
                return (
                <ButtonToolbar style={{width: 17+ 'em'}}>
                <Button  disabled={disable} style={{width: 5 + 'em'}}>Detail</Button>
                <Button onClick={this.clickDisable} style={{width: 5 + 'em'}}>Disable</Button>
                </ButtonToolbar>)
              }
            }) ;


function select(state) {  
    return {  
        disabled: state.disabled
    }  
}  

const NewDetailButton = connect(select)(DetailButton);
```

**rootReducer**

```
var rootReducer = Redux.combineReducers({
        reducreForButtonGroup,reducreForButtonGroup2
    });


ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
  <NewDetailButton/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('divDetailBtn')
);
```

---

### New reducer

---

**New reducer i want to add**

```
var initialState = {
        value:15
        }
```

**Action creators**

```
function clickAdd() {
  return {
      type: 'CLICK_ADD'
  }
}
```

**New reducre**

```
 function reducreForButtonGroup(state = initialState, action) {
      if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
        return 0
      }
      var value;
      switch(action.type) {
          case 'CLICK_ADD': {
              console.log("2");
    
              return {
                  value: state.value + 1
                  }
    
          }
          default :{
              return state
          }
      }
    }
```

**Component**

```
var ButtonGroup = React.createClass({
    
     clickAdd(event) {  
            this.props.dispatch(clickAdd());  
        }  ,
    
  render() {
      
      const { value } = this.props;     
      
        return (
          <ButtonToolbar style={{width: 17+ 'em'}} >
          <Button  id="search"   style={{width: 5 + 'em'}}>{value}</Button>
          <Button  onClick={this.clickAdd} style={{width: 5 + 'em'}}>Create</Button>
          </ButtonToolbar> 
        );
      }
});
```

**Mapstatetoprops**

```
function select(state) {  
    return {  
        value: state.reducreForButtonGroup.value
    }  
}  

const NewButtonGroup = connect(select)(ButtonGroup);
```

Comment: Have you posted the full code of your reducer? If yes, your reducer doesn't return anything, it must return a new state.

Comment: yes sorry i add the full code of the reducer . could you please find me to find the problem? its fail to initialState and didnt change the disabled of the button when i call the action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disabled` is not present in props, itself. It's present in `props.reducreForButtonGroup2`

So change the following

```
function select(state) {  
    return {  
        disabled: state.disabled
    }  
}
```

to,

```
function select(state) {  
    return {  
        disabled: state.reducreForButtonGroup2.disabled
    }  
}
```

Currently, it's just undefined. Hence, it never gets disabled, no matter what.

The right way to look up the store for data is to look for it by the reducer name. Since you declared the reducer by the name `reducreForButtonGroup2`, anything you return from the reducer (i.e, `{ disabled: true }` or `{ disabled: false }`) will be available in `state.reducreForButtonGroup2` in `mapStateToProps`. So to check the button state, you'll need to fetch the state of the store from `stats.reducreForButtonGroup2.disabled`.

This way, you can now pass down this value as a prop by returning it. If you return `{ disabled: state.reducreForButtonGroup2.disabled }` in mapStateToProps (ie selection in this case), your component will receive `this.props.disabled` which will have the value.

Just to see how it works, return a different object from mapStateToProps. Eg:

```
function select(state) {  
    return {  
        isButtonDisabled: state.reducreForButtonGroup2.disabled
    }  
}
```

The prop in the component will now become,

```
const { isButtonDisabled } = this.props
```

Comment: thx for replying , it shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'disabled' of undefined after change to this.props.reducreForButtonGroup2; am i setting the mapstatetoprops wrongly??

Comment: Updated my answer. You can continue to `this.props.disabled` since mapStateToProps will expose a prop `disabled` whose value is fetched from state.reducreForButtonGroup2.disabled

Comment: thx so much!! it works , so if i have another reducer and mapStateToProps,i just set it the same way right?

Comment: Yes :) Use its name in the mapStateToProps